# Deploy Yeoman Angular App to Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, yeoman

I know there are some instructions how to do so (eg like [this](https://medium.com/@3runjo/how-to-deploy-a-grunt-project-on-heroku-c227cb1ddc56) or [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-yeomanangular-app-heroku/)).

But i cannot seem to get it running.

My server.js looks like this:

```
var app, express, gzippo, morgan;
gzippo = require('gzippo');
express = require('express');
morgan = require('morgan');
app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Even if I run my server.js via node locally the rendered webpage just says

> Cannot GET /

so my Heroku Application renders the same message.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with Yeoman and trying to deploy to Heroku -- using the angular-fullstack generator. Turned out that my generator was out of date and updating it did the trick.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Every Yeoman project is not necessarily a `generator-angular-fullstack`

Comment: Didn't say they were. Was simply pointing out that updating his generator could potentially help, especially if the generator itself has documentation on deployment.

Comment: If you don't really know or have a doubt, you should ask and / or put this in a comment